# How to document a type in enunciate?

Tags: jaxb, xsd, auto-generate, enunciate, jaxb2-maven-plugin

How to get the description field on a type populated in the generated enunciate documentation?

We are generating classes from jaxb using jaxb2-maven-plugin. No matter how I document a element either using the `<xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>` or the

```
<xsd:appinfo>
   <jaxb:class>
     <jaxb:javadoc>
       </jaxb:javadoc>
    </jaxb:class>
</xsd:appinfo>
```

it is overwritten in the generated classes. Can I somehow disable the this auto-generated javadoc from this plugin? Or what does enunciate really expect me to do let me document on a field level?

**Note** that the comment I write on class-level/type does show up in the generated class and in the enunciated generated documentation.

We are using enunciate (v.1.26.2) and  jaxb2-maven-plugin (v. 1.5)

Answer (score 0):

So you're wondering how to get Enunciate to *not* use the Javadocs on the class?

One way might be to compile the JAXB-generated classes and run Enunciate against the compiled classes instead of the source code.

Comment: No, I am wondering how to get enunciate to display the javadoc comments for getters and setter for instance variables (elements in xsd). In the generated documentation there is a table for them stating things like type, optional, but the rows where the expected comment should be shown is *NEVER* populated.